# Android: Stop video player when page is scrolled and player is not viewable anymore

Tags: android, android-view, android-scrollview

I have an application with several views inside an ScrollView. Some of my views are video players.

I want to pause player when page is scrolled and video player is not seen anymore in the page. So, how can I track when a view is not viewable inside page?

Comment: @ VSB did you figure this out?  
I have a non-scrolling RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView.
How can I stop the players inside the RV when they go off screen?

Comment: @Avramo Sorry, since I have asked this a long time ago I could not remember that.